# Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: javascript, java, compiler-errors, bioinformatics

please i'm connected to the server as simple user using my personal computer ,i try to execute a software (qualimap ) but it didn't work, it shows this error message

```
No protocol specified Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:115)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:103)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:82)
    at java.awt.Window.initGC(Window.java:475)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:495)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:233)
    at org.bioinfo.ngs.qc.qualimap.gui.frames.HomeFrame.<init>(HomeFrame.java:153)
    at org.bioinfo.ngs.qc.qualimap.main.NgsSmartMain.launchGUI(NgsSmartMain.java:170)
    at
```

org.bioinfo.ngs.qc.qualimap.main.NgsSmartMain.main(NgsSmartMain.java:53)

how can solve that without using any sudo command because i can't run it 
Thank you

Comment: Windows, Linux or Mac (your personal computer)? And how are you connected to the server?

Comment: Thank you for your reply , it s Linux and im connected SSH connection

Comment: I'm assuming then you already have X11 or Wayland running, and that you use `ssh` to connect. Use `ssh -Y hostname` to enable X11 forwarding from your local linux machine to the remote linux server. Then you should be able to run your application. You can also add `ForwardX11 yes` to your `$HOME/.ssh/config` file (**locally**).

Comment: i tried  ssh -Y  hostname after i got this error msg::  Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyException in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:10.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Comment: Did you use `-Y`? That should have enabled `ForwardAgent`. You're on Linux on both sides? Try adding a `-v` to `ssh`. It will be *verbose*. You could also try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496877/52050).

Comment: Does this actually involve JavaScript at all?  Java and JavaScript are very different things, and this appears to be only a Java problem.

Comment: Yes i tried it , and i added -v , but still the same  error : exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using 'localhost:11.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.

Comment: @VGR It's an X11 problem. There's no code here. And certainly no compiler errors either.

Comment: The DISPLAY variable looks correct for SSH, but until something like an `xterm` works you won't be able to get anywhere. It's entirely an X11 issue at this point. That is make sure any X11 application works. Not just your desired application.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I was only interested in whether the `javascript` tag should be removed.

Comment: @VGR I think all of the tags should be removed; and a x11 tag added. ssh tag might be appropriate too.